# How to get the date value of current date?

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I want an `if` condition that could check if the day value of the current date is 1. I have applied the logic:

```
if(Date.Today().month()==1)
```

But the above results in months. How can I check for days instead?

Comment: Do you want to check if the current day is 1?

Comment: yes. please suggest some logic here.

Comment: @p.samruddhi Why don't you check `if(Date.Today().day()==1)`

Comment: Someone needs coffee......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do the same thing with the `day` method of the `date` class:

```
if(Date.Today().day()==1)
```